# Why is this trigger making some of my inserts hang?

Tags: mysql, triggers

The trigger is as follows:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `Conturi_BI` BEFORE INSERT ON `Conturi` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.CUI_cod = digits(NEW.CUI);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm just applying a digits function to a user input for faster matching and duplicates search, but ever since I implemented it some of my Inserts just hang. I made a similar one for updates and it doesn't have the same problem.

The digits function is created by me and the trigger and inserts work fine most of the time.

The digits function, as requested:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE c CHAR(1);
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str );
  REPEAT
    BEGIN
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 );
      IF c BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c);
      END IF;
      SET i = i + 1;
      END;
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT;
  RETURN ret;
END
```

Comment: Are you sure MySQL has a `digits` function? I couldn't find it in the Doc. It doesn't work on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2950)  but I found it for [DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref%2Ffdigits.htm)

Comment: The digits function was added by me, also the trigger works most of the time.

Comment: Then please show the code of the `digits` function. The problem might be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `digit` function does not work if you pass `null` to it. It will loop forever. Try it with

```
select digits(null)
```

So every time `NEW.CUI` is null then it will make your inserts hang. You could add a `null` check at the beginning of your function:

```
if str is null
then 
   return '';
end if;
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is, and this is judging from your "some" statement, that you get a problem with [lock contention](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29#Granularity).

If I understand your trigger right, on (actually before) a write to table A you trigger your procedure, which in turn alters EVERY record in the same table A the write is for, exclusively locking every row in a single transaction.

Doing this during another transaction can very well lead to a [deadlock](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Deadlock) situation, where your trigger waits to upgrade a lock, which the other transaction waits for yours to finish (deadlocks in a nutshell, if you will).

Success in this endeavor depends on the implementation of the database driver at least. Locking a row, then locking it again in a triggered transaction most database drivers assume that the transaction can be widened, however, some databases are not able to see that the transactions come from the same connection and deal with them separately.

Comment: Shouldn't the trigger only lock the newly added rows and not the entire table?